# dynamic import() not loading CSS Modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, css-modules, code-splitting

I'm trying to add a dynamic import() to my React component, and their working fine. Except for one huge detail: only the JavaScript is being loaded but the CSS, provided by CSS Modules, aren't.

Here's the code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

class Routes extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      home: null
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    import("../home/Home").then(Home => this.setState({ home: Home.default }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={this.state.home} />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

This is what should happen:

[image]

This is what is happening:

[image]

React: 15.5.4
Webpack: 2.5.1

Comment: Do you want to post a repro repo to exemplify the issue? It's hard to work off of what you have posted.

Comment: What does importing the component and setting state in CDM accomplish that using a regular import does not?

Comment: @lux route code-splitting

Comment: @MatheusLima Cool, thanks

Comment: @JamesKraus I'll try to setup asap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.
I just had to pass allChunks: true to ExtractTextPlugin